Realtek ethernet driver disabled both my ethernet and internet drivers without installing new ones
I have a Debian 12 system that I always connect with an ethernet cable. I saw that it wasn't running at its advertised speed (~100 Mb/s vs. 500Mb/s), so I tried to install its driver from the manufacturer's website (Realtek), and upon unzipping it with tar -xf DRIVER-NAME.tar.bz2, and running the executable with chmod +x autorun.sh; ./autorun.sh (I am logged in with root) it returns these three errors:

Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/6.1.0-21-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:182: clean] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:4: clean] Error 2


I'm supposing that the first step in autorun.sh is to disable the old driver or delete it, then install the new one. However, while installing, these three errors stop it from installing the drivers. I am posting this question on another computer which has an Internet connection. However, the Debian system neither has an ethernet connection, nor does it have a Wi-Fi connection, so it's completely cut off.
I do have access to a computer with an Internet connection and a USB flash drive, so I can manually install packages using apt. The only thing is, I've already tried it. It is important to note that upon first running autorun.sh, it returned an error that the command make was not found. So, I used the flash drive to manually install it using a .deb file. Then, it threw up the errors previously mentioned, and I found that there is actually a package to install the driver, r8168-dkms, so I copied over the .deb file, but when I ran it, there were about 20+ dependencies that I hadn't installed, but this time, I couldn't find most of them on deb.debian.org.
